# Nodejs on xml to json error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to convert some XML to json

I have here this into a function

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString

   _.map(dataset, function(items) {
     return _.map(items, function(item) {
       cancel = parseString(item.XX_CANCEL, function(item) {return item;});
       dropdown = parseString(item.XX_VIEW, function(item) {return item;});
       fillOpen = parseString(item['XX_FILL OPEN'], function(item) {return item;});
       return item;
     });
   });
```

when I try to execute it, I get this error

```
/home/mretana/Documents/Projects/capilleiraclickandgamblebackend/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:493
        throw exception;
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
    at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString ...
```

just for you to know, for example if I remove the `parseString(...)` and do

```
cancel = item.XX_CANCEL;

console.log(cancel)
logs ---> <element><element_type>BASIC_CHECKBOX</element_type><element_call/><element_content>1</element_content></element>
```

it logs that XML element, that is why I am doing it with the `parseString`,

```
cancel = parseString(item.XX_CANCEL, function(item) {return item;});
```

so, what do you think is going on ?

All I need is to convert those XML elements into JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the API of xml2js, it is evident that `parseString` accepts a callback using the standard form of `function(err, res)`, whereas you are using the form `function(item)`.